# slideUp/slideDown animation only in one section

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have simple problem with my jQuery code. I created row of jumbotrons and a few of this jumbotrons are hidden with CSS and on button click I display them. This work for me but I have a problem with the animation on event slideUp. I want to see how my jumbotrons are slowly and animated hidden but when I click on my button Show less animation goes to bottom of page - not back to heading Example as I want.

here is my code on [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/mask1/pen/mdEegYQ)

```
$("#pr").click(function() {
  if ($(this).text() == "Show more") {
    $(this).html("<button class=\"btn custom-btn1 \" type=\"submit\">Show less</button></a>");
    $(".hide-me").slideDown(1000);
  } else {
    $(this).html("<button class=\"btn custom-btn1 \" type=\"submit\">Show more</button></a>");
    $(".hide-me").slideUp("slow");
  }
  return false;
});
```

Comment: I don't fully understand what the problem is, I had a look at the Codepen and other than one of the items popping up I don't see anything wrong

Comment: i want it work like this: https://codepen.io/mask1/pen/dyXYEBx
so on click button it scroll back to top of my section but if i add second section it allways scroll down...like in my first post

Comment: Add `window.scrollTo(0,$("#top-h2-with-text-example").position().top);` before `$(".hide-me").slideUp("slow");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add an animation (that doesn't get queued) to scroll up straight after slideUp is called.

```
$("#pr").click(function() {
  if ($(this).text() == "Show more") {
    $(this).html("<button class=\"btn custom-btn1 \" type=\"submit\">Show less</button></a>");
    $(".hide-me").slideDown(1000);
  } else {
    $(this).html("<button class=\"btn custom-btn1 \" type=\"submit\">Show more</button></a>");
    $(".hide-me").slideUp("slow");
    const body = $("html, body");
    body.animate({scrollTop: $(".portfolio").offset().top}, {queue: false});
  }
  return false;
});
```

Comment: but  it's not a smooth animation... :/

Comment: @mask I've updated the answer - instead of the callback, just have another animation that doesn't get queued.

Comment: this scroll to top of page. and i have some other section before section with jumbotrons and i want to scroll only to top of section with jumbotrons.

Comment: @mask I've updated example, you just need to scroll to the top position of the portfolio section.